# unbound method with instance as first argument got string but requires something else

Tags: python, oop, methods

```
#Maps.py
class Maps(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.animals = []
        self.currently_occupied = {}

    def add_animal(self, name):
        self.animals.append(name)
        self.currently_occupied = {robot:[0, 0]}



#animal.py
class Animal(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        import maps
        maps.add_animal(rbt)
        self.name = name


#Tproject.py
from Animal import Animal
Fred = Animal("Fred")
```

gives me this an error that looks like this

TypeError: unbound method add_animal() must be called with Maps instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

but i dont know what it means and i cannot figure it out searching through google or yahoo :(

Comment: As a rule of thumb, imports should happen on the module scope, preferably at the top. You also need the Maps class from the maps module, not the module itself (so maps.Maps).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need an instance of Maps, not the Maps class:

```
 maps.Maps.add_animal("Fred") # gives error

 mymap = maps.Map()

 mymap.add_animal("Fred") # should work
```

So you should either have a mymap attribute on the Animal class, per Animal instance or as a global object (whatever works best for your case).

Answer (score 3):

You're calling an unbound method, meaning you're accessing a method from a class itself, and not through an instance (so Python doesn't know which instance should be used as `self`). This code shouldn't give that error as shown, but I assume you're doing something like

```
maps.Maps.add_animal(rbt)
```

It's not clear what you're trying to do, or I'd offer a suggestion as to how to fix it.