# unbound method must be called with X instance as first argument (got X instance instead)

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

I get the following error message in my Python 2-Code (2.7.9):
*TypeError: unbound method issueTransitionJIRA() must be called with AccessCd instance as first argument (got AccessCd instance instead)*

So python complains that the 1st argument should be the class instance which I actually passed..?! Certainly I'm missing something, but I did not get it yet, searching other answers on similar error messages... Can anyone help/explain me? Thanks a lot!

Here is my code structure:

main-file *w32AccessCd.py*:

```
import transitionStatusTracking

class AccessCd:
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.main()

    def main():
        tST = transitionStatusTracking.tStateTrack(self)
        tST.setup()

    # ...

    def issueTransitionJ(self, issuekey, workflowcmd):
        # ...
        return True     


accesscd = AccessCd()
```

module-file *transitionStatusTracking.py*:

```
from w32AccessCd import AccessCd

class tStateTrack:

    def __init__(self, ACCESSCD):
        self.ACCESSCD = ACCESSCD

    def setup(self):
        AccessCd.issueTransitionJ(self.ACCESSCD, self.key, "error")
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unbound method issueTransitionJ() must be called with AccessCd instance as first argument (got AccessCd instance instead)
```

Comment: error is here:  AccessCd.issueTransitionJ(self.ACCESSCD, self.key, "error")

Comment: How do you run your file? Is either module used as the main script with Python, like `python w32AccessCd.py` perhaps?

Comment: @felipsmartins: Thanks for the quick answer, but what do you mean? Which part of that line is the error? Or what should I do instead?
(btw the argument "error" is definitely not the error, it is just a funny random thing that it occurs here ;))

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, at the moment I am testing the program with exactly that call "python w32AccessCd.py". Later on that main class (of this file) is going to be called from within a service wrapper.

Comment: @Kris: right, but that is the exact reason your code fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Python runs a script, the file is stored in the `__main__` namespace. Importing it as a module, on the other hand, puts it in the `<name-of-module>` namespace.

You are running `w32AccessCd.py` as the main script, defining the `__main__.AccessCd`.

You then import `transitionStatusTracking`, which turns around and imports the `w32AccessCd`. This creates a **second** copy of that module, as the `w32AccessCd` namespace. You now **also** have `w32AccessCd.AccessCd`. This is a separate class, and is distinct from the other class.

What happens next is this:

- `accesscd = AccessCd()` creates an instance of type `__main__.AccessCd`.
- `__main__.AccessCd.__init__` calls `__main__.AccessCd.main`.
- `__main__.AccessCd.main` creates an instance of `transitionStatusTracking.tStateTrack`, passing in the `__main__.AccessCd` instance in.
- You call the `transitionStatusTracking.tStateTrack.setup` method, which tries to use the `w32AccessCd.AccessCd.issueTransitionJ()` method with a `__main__.AccessCd` instance, and the call fails.

You have three options to fix this:

- In the `transitionStatusTracking` module, import from `__main__`:

  ```
  from __main__ import AccessCd
  ```

  and to make the circular import work, you'd have to move the `import transitionStatusTracking` line to *below* the `class AccessCd` block, otherwise the class is not defined yet. Alternatively use `import __main__` and reference `__main__.AccessCd` in your code.

  Now you have the same class.
- Create a third file to do the scripting; say `main.py`, with:

  ```
  from w32AccessCd import AccessCd
  accesscd = AccessCd()
  ```

  and remove the `accesscd = AcessCd()` line from the `w32AccessCd` module. Now there will be just the `w32AccessCd.AccessCd` class instance being passed around.
- Call the method *directly* rather than unbound:

  ```
  def setup(self):
      self.ACCESSCD.issueTransitionJ(self.key, "error")
  ```

  This ensures the method is bound to the right instance and it no longer matters where the class came from.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanations!
No3 worked for me! :)

Maybe you can help me too, why no1 did not work, but resulted in that issue...?

    from __main__ import AccessCd
ImportError: cannot import name AccessCd

Comment: @Kris: ah, you get a circular import. You'd have to do the import *after defining the class*.